# Android ActionBar custom text font

Tags: java, android, шрифты, actionbar, span

Большинство людей в интернете советуют для этого следующую конструкцию:

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "My_Font.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
```

Но у меня горит красным `(this, "My_Font.ttf")`. Нашёл на англицком StackOverFlow брата по несчастью, ему посоветовали:

> please get the activity/application context and pass it to
>   constructor rather than this as this will give currently running class
>   while you need the current context.

Я пытался. Сначала писал `MyActivity.getApplicationContext();` вместо `this`. Он сказал

> non static method cannot be referenced from static context.

Потом перед конструкцией писал `Context context; context = getApplicationContext();` и в скобках `Context context` вместо `this`. В этом случае он подчёркивал уже пробел между `Context` и `context`. Я чувствую, что хожу вокруг да около, но всё никак не попадаю. Что делать?

## UPDATE#1

Нашёл полный код применения конструкции. Красным больше ничто не подчёркивается, но Activity вылетает.

```
class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
        /** An <code>LruCache</code> for previously loaded typefaces. */
        private  LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache = new LruCache<String, Typeface>(5);

        private Typeface mTypeface;

        /**
         * Load the {@link Typeface} and apply to a spannable.
         */
        public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
            mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

            if (mTypeface == null) {
                mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext()
                        .getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));

                // Cache the loaded Typeface
                sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
            p.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
            tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        }}
    Context context;
    context = getApplicationContext();
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(context, "FDMedian.ttf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
```

## UPDATE#2

логи с ошибками:

```
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames.Activity2}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames.Activity2$1TypefaceSpan.<init>(Activity2.java:35)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:54)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
01-25 00:18:42.939 20035-20035/com.morpheus.sketc_000.morpheuscompanygames E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Вместо this нужно написать просто context (с маленькой буквы) для второго случая. Потом нужно читать о передаче параметров в методы в какой-нибудь книжке и что тип объекта в этом случае не указыается. Потом читать, в каких случаях тип указывается. В общем Шилдта книжку вам надо прочитать, потом уже пограмму писать

Comment: @pavlofff, не работает просто context. Я б почитал книжку, но времени нет, нужно срочно программу сделать.

Comment: Внутри какого метода приведённый вами код?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , Внутри OnCreate

Comment: Ну а шрифт-то у вас имеется? И с какой ошибкой приложение падает? Вы всё не хотите нам всей инфы давать. Этак вам помочь вообще никак нельзя. Совсем.

Comment: А путь к шрифту не нужно указать? Либо берите его из asset, либо указывайте реальный путь до файла.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько причин, которые могут вызвать `java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made`:

- используете неправильное расширение
- разместили шрифты в папке с ресурсами (корень assets), а не внутри
  `assets/fonts/`
- не добавили файл с шрифтами
- имя файла с шрифтом должен быть написан строчными буквами(например, надо 
  переименовать `MyFont.ttf` в `myfont.ttf`)